# How to convert KML to GPX in php

Tags: php, kml, gpx

what i need to do is develop a webpage that allows a user to specify a KML file on the hard drive and my code at the back end (in PHP) will then generate the GPX file for that KML. I cant seem to find pointers on how to write the code for it, should be pretty simple parsing techniques im guessing.

i need to achieve something like this tool here is doing: http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/convert_input

but they have not provided an API for it. any pointers as to how i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to know that this conversion may work only for a small subset of KML files. Because KML is a much broader file (XML) format than GPX. As wikipedia [say](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) KML is intended for "expressing geographic annotation and visualization". Those can be shapes that can't be represented in GPX. GPX is just for GPS data -- data recorder by the GPS (tracks, waypoints) or created on the computer to be used in GPS later (routes, waypoints).

That said, gpsvisualiser [mostly uses](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/gpsbabel/) [gpsbabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/). This is not exactly a PHP solution but if you can install run an external command from PHP (gpsbabel) this would be the easiest way to implement it.

Comment: okay, im currently only working with .kml files downloaded from maps.google.com after you save a track information to My Places. Couldnt find any PHP repositories that allow such a a conversion so im up to writing my own code which will read the file and hopefully create a replica of gpx files that gpsvisualizer outputs. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this php script? [Convert from Google KML to GPS Exchange Format GPX with PHP -- Blog of Travis Hydzik](http://thydzik.com/convert-from-google-kml-to-gps-exchange-format-gpx/)

Works well.

I encountered only one error when processing with the script, which is:
*Undefined offset: 1 in kml-to-gpx.php on line 147*
which is caused by blank spaces before the first coordinate, and after the last coordinate, in any  set in the source kml file. This blank space is added as latitude and longitude figure despite having no numerical value.

You can make the file download by adding

```
$u_filename = $u_parts['filename'] . ".gpx";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='$u_filename';");
```

after

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
```